# WoW API: demote all people with some rank?

Tags: api, lua, world-of-warcraft

I would like to **demote** (rank down) **every member of my guild with a specific rank** (e.g. all Newbies to Incomers)

---  any ideas **how to do this in World of Warcraft API ?**

(Im guessing some loop over all guild members' names testing if rank and demote then? - please write example if so)

Thank you for your future answers :)

Comment: I'm not a WoW expert, but according to the [site](http://www.wowwiki.com/World_of_Warcraft_API#Introduction) its API is written in Lua, not C. Maybe you should remove the C tag and add the Lua tag.

Comment: @wowapier The only thing Lua has in common with C is that it is a programming language. Other than that, they couldn't be more different. JavaScript, which is a kissing cousin to Lua (dynamically typed, garbage collected, with closures, inheritance via prototypes, etc.), at least has C-like *syntax*. Lua doesn't even have that.

Comment: I was pointing that its more C like than Pascal like - you said it yourself "kissing cousin" < still related - and STILL I dont get why would anybody rank down this question? Its a really interesting issue...

Comment: I said *JavaScript* is a kissing cousin to Lua, not C.  And it's *Lua* that has Pascal-like syntax, while JavaScript has C-like syntax. Lua really couldn't be any more distant from C, as far as languages go. The only thing they share is that they are both imperative. As for downvoting, I did, because you're basically asking someone to write this for you and have clearly done *no* work whatsoever. None. I used to write addons myself. This stuff is very easy to Google. Stackoverflow is not supposed to be a replacement for Google.

Comment: You are probably looking for this function: http://www.wowwiki.com/API_GetGuildRosterInfo ; for a for loop you could use a GetNumGuildMembers() and as you get the name in the loop use a GuildDemote("name") ? I hope I understood your question correctly :)

Comment: and @Mud cmon man dont eat him just because he thinks an "old c way"...  for me Lua reminds me more like Fortran or something like that :)

Comment: Not trying to eat him, just clarify. It's possibly he's never even *seen* Lua, given that's a very rare and conspicuous example of a modern language with Pascal-like syntax, but he said it's *not* Pascal-like. Maybe he's actually thinking of JavaScript?

Comment: Well I saw Lua before and I am sorry but few examples just seemed they had the C approach :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I played, the the first place I'd always look was wowwiki. Here's the list of [guild functions](http://www.wowwiki.com/World_of_Warcraft_API#Guild_Functions). Looks like you can call `GetGuildRosterInfo` from 1 to `GetNumGuildMember` times (or until `GetGuildRosterInfo(N)` returns `nil`) to get player name and rank, then call `GuildDemote` to demote players.

Something like this (totally untested; I don't even have WoW installed these days):

```
for i=1,GetNumGuildMembers() do
    local name, rank = GetGuildRosterInfo(i)
    if rank == "The rank you're iterested in" then
        GuildDemote(name)
    end
end
```

You can try out API calls in game. You can even write most of your addon in game. When I played, I wrote quite a few addons for myself and published [a few](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/author-44124.html). One of them (Hack) was an in-game Lua script editor. I think someone has picked up the ball on that and kept it going. You should look to get something like that.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, but how to write it on more lines ? (Lua pages seem to have their loops on more lines(so do you)) when I try to do so it doesn't work

Comment: Lua, for the most part, doesn't care about white space. You can write the entire script on one line.  Better, though, would be to get something like DevPad so you can write readable code in game.

Comment: Well I tried to put your code into the browser address field end then paste it after the /run and it seems to work now :) Thanks for the example ! :) - but one more question - it really can't be done on more lines directly in ingame macros? :(

Comment: "it really can't be done on more lines directly in ingame macros?"  Nope. Macros aren't Lua (though they can contain Lua, via /run).

Answer (score 1):

This is a clarification for the rest of the OPs question about being able to do this in a macro.

Here is something I had in one of my macros, formatted so you can read it here:

```
/run for i=0,0 do local instanceName, instanceDesc, backgroundTexture, buttonTexture, 
    titleBackground, mapID, instanceLink = EJ_GetSearchResult(i); if mapID then print
    (i,instanceName, mapID) end end

/dump GetLFGDungeonInfo(20)
```

Here's the same thing formatted so that you could jsut copy and paste it into a macro. Each command is on one line. You can have multiple commands which are run sequentialy:

```
/run for i=0,0 do local instanceName, instanceDesc, backgroundTexture, buttonTexture, titleBackground, mapID, instanceLink = EJ_GetSearchResult(i); if mapID then print(i,instanceName, mapID) end end
/dump GetLFGDungeonInfo(20)
```

Heres the accepted answer again:

```
for i=1,GetNumGuildMembers() do
    local name, rank = GetGuildRosterInfo(i)
    if rank == "The rank you're iterested in" then
        GuildDemote(name)
    end
end
```

Here it is formatted for pasting into a macro:

```
/run for i=1,GetNumGuildMembers() do local name, rank = GetGuildRosterInfo(i); if rank == "The rank you're iterested in" then GuildDemote(name) end end
```

Notice the simicolon ';' between the two statements in the same block on the same line. This is good practice for making the code unambiguous and a little easier to read.